# Merge variables in a row with same correlation value

Tags: r, merge, correlation, tidy

I have a df with correlation values between variables:

```
input <- data.frame(Var1 = c("A","B","A","D","G", "H", "I"), Var2 = 
c("B","C","E","F", "F", "J", "K"), Corr_Value = c(1,1,1,0.7,0.7, 1,1), 
stringsAsFactors = F)
```

As it is shown, (A = B), (A = E), and (B = C)

I would like to obtain a df like 'output', in which, all variable relations are in one row (A = B = C = E)

```
output <- data.frame(Var1 = c("A","D", "H", "I"),
Var2 = c("B","F", "J", "K"),
Var3 = c("C","G", "NA", "NA"),
Var4 = c("E", "NA", "NA", "NA"),
Corr_Value = c(1,0.7,1,1))
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Your input does not specify that H/J and I/K are related, and yet they are related in the output.

Comment: @KerryJackson fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `igraph` to get the expected output

```
library(igraph)
g1 <- graph.data.frame(input[-3], directed = TRUE)
cl <- clusters(g1)
lst <- cluster_edge_betweenness(g1)
lst1 <- lst[1:4]
attr(lst, "class") <- NULL


out <- setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(lst1,
           `length<-`, max(lengths(lst1)))), paste0("Var", 1:4))
out$Corr_value <- input$Corr_Value[match(mapply(`[`, lst1, cl$csize), input$Var2)]
out
#  Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Corr_value
#1    A    B    C    E        1.0
#2    D    G    F <NA>        0.7
#3    H    J <NA> <NA>        1.0
#4    I    K <NA> <NA>        1.0
```

Comment: I obtain the following message when running line 7: error in names(object) -  'names' attribute [4] must be the same length as the vector [2] @akrun

Comment: @torakxkz  Oops, the order in which I pasted the code here is different.  Sorry. Updated.  Now, it should work.

Comment: I had to make some modifications to adapt to my original df, but it works. Thank you. Harder than I thought